# Is analytic continuation the same as solving a PDE boundary problem with Cauchy Riemann

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, divergent-series, analytic-continuation

I was considering the idea of analytic continuation:

Let $ U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a subinterval (perhaps all of R). Then suppose we have some smooth function defined $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we want to "analytically continue" this function to the complex plane.

We could look at the power series of the $f$ and set up sheafs and start expanding to find an analytic continuation OR...

We could ask "what is a holomorphic function equal to this function on the interval $U$?"

I.E. we want find $u(x,y), v(x,y)$ satisfying

$$ \frac{ \partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\ \frac{ \partial u}{\partial y} = - \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}  \\ u(x,0) = f(x), x \in U $$

Would there be a unique such $u,v$ pair? If there is such a unique pair would it then be THE "analytic continuation" of $f$ to the complex plane?

Comment: first $f$ needs to be real analytic as otherwise no hope; then you get a continuation to an open plane set $V$ that contains $U$ but how big $V$ can be, of course depends on the situation; if $V$ is the whole plane the continuation is unique but otherwise you may have many continuations on various $V$ as there is no maximal $V$ - for example if $f(x)=\log (x^2+1)$ you can continue it to any plane open set that excludes disjoint Jordan arcs joining $\pm i$ with infinity; also any "maximal" $V$ may be quite small as one sees by putting dense countable singularities close to the real line

Comment: so coming back to PDE's the situation is very tricky as in general you do not know the domain of the solutions, only that they must exist in some $V$ open containing $U$ assuming of course $f$ real analytic on $U$; and of course, they are not generally unique

Comment: Can the set of solutions be given a structure? Perhaps we want to say something like "for each solution up monodromy there exists a unique summation method for divergent series". That feels like it could be promising